# Insert data in bash prompt with script

Tags: bash, console

I created a bash script that perform some operations inside a while loop.
In one command, the console asks for an input and I have no idea how to provide this input in order to continue with my script.

```
while read line;
do
    string_array=($line)
    username=${string_array[0]}
    password=${string_array[1]}
    kinit $username
        ===> here I need to enter the $password and press "ENTER" to continue

done <myfile
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your *main* `while-loop` to read from a different file descriptor than `stdin` and use `read` to read from `stdin` and use `-s` to suppress text from showing up in console.

```
while read -u 3 line; do
    # Your rest of the code 
    read -s -p "Enter password: " password
done 3<myfile
```

Comment: So, after the command "kinit $username", when I need to enter password, I use the command => read -s -p "Enter password: " password  ???

Comment: does not work :(  the console is still stuck at "Enter password for user...."

Comment: @user3472065: You are either 1) not using the code as I suggested 2) or you have not posted the complete script. I did not have a string `Enter password for user`, do you have other `read` commands in your script?

Comment: I solved the issue doing that:  echo $password | kinit $username

Comment: Thanks anyway for the support!!!